# Can't read property 'style' of null from dynamic html code

Tags: javascript, html

I am refactoring old code and am unable to find a solution to the typeerror (I understand the use of eval is frowned upon but in my case there is no need for security).

I have objects like:

```
var Ansys = {key:'ansyskeys', loaded:0, display: "none", otherkey: 'anotherkey'};
var Cadence = {key:"cdskeys", loaded:0, display: "none", otherkey: 'cotherkey'};
```

I had previous HTML code that was static that I am trying to refactor to be dynamic:

```
 <div id="ansyskeys" style="display:none">
    <select id="anotherkey" size="5" onchange="selectOther('anotherkey')"></select>
</div>
```

Which is called from (vendor holds the name of my object I want):

```
document.getElementById(eval(vendor).key).style.display = eval(vendor).display;
```

How would I go about changing the HTML to be something like (I am using display in my object for something else)

```
<div id="eval(vendor).key" style="display:none">
    <select id="eval(vendor).otherkey" size="5" onchange="selectOther(eval(vendor).otherkey)"></select>
</div>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need eval() at all? Eval receives string as input, but you already have objects to work with.

Comment: eval is turning the string name to a literal so instead of saying vendor.key and getting undefined returned, eval(vendor).key acts as if it is Ansys.key

Answer (score 1):

If `vendor` holds the object you need:

```
var key = vendor.key;
var otherkey = vendor.otherkey;
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');

var html = '<select id="' + otherkey + '" size="5" onchange="selectOther('+ otherkey + ')"></select>';

myDiv.innerHTML = html;
myDiv.id = key;
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
```